# write special string to url

Tags: php, asp.net

how to write special string such as %31 to url.

Comment: Your question is much to general.  Please provide a specific example, or it will quickly be closed.

Comment: If you don't want `%31` to be decoded, replace `%` with `%25`. If not, then I don't know what you want.

Comment: when write %31 to url this convert to 1.

Comment: Please use your favorite search engine for "URL encoding"

Answer (score 2):

Your tags suggest a bit of indecisiveness when it comes to the language you are using, so I'll assume PHP.

Use [the urlencode function](http://uk.php.net/urlencode) to escape illegal and special characters for inclusion in a URL.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to encode the `%` to `%25` - so `%31` turns to `%2531`.

Just lookup any [ASCII table](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ascii+table) for the decimal value of the character.

Answer (score 0):

Just encode the percent sign itself so that when the browser parses the string it translates it properly.

Here's a link with various characters and their encoding:
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Answer (score 0):

[urlencode](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) is probably your friend :)